# Next js Modal Hydration error in client side rendering

Tags: next.js, modal-dialog, hydration, client-side-rendering

I'm grappling with a perplexing issue in my Next.js and React application. Despite my efforts to prevent server-side rendering using useEffect, I'm encountering hydration errors that are proving challenging to resolve.

The core of the problem lies in the CreateServerModal component, an integral part of my application. This component utilizes the Dialog components from a UI library and is invoked within the layout.tsx file. The modal is meant to handle server requests for creating a new server, and everything appears to work as intended on the client side.

Here's the relevant code for the CreateServerModal:

```js
"use client";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { useModal } from "@/hooks/use-modal-store";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import FileUpload from "../file-upload";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Server name is required.",
  }),
  imageUrl: z.string().min(1, {
    message: "Server image is required.",
  }),
});

export const CreateServerModal = () => {
  const { isOpen, onClose, type } = useModal();
  const router = useRouter();

  const isModalOpen = isOpen && type === "createServer";

  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      imageUrl: "",
    },
  });

  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("/api/servers", values);
      form.reset();
      router.refresh();
      onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    form.reset();
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={isModalOpen} onOpenChange={handleClose}>
      <DialogContent className="overflow-hidden bg-white p-0 text-black">
        <DialogHeader className="px-6 pt-8">
          <DialogTitle className="text-center text-2xl font-bold">
            Customize your server
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription className="text-center text-zinc-500">
            Give your new server a personality with a name and an icon. You can
            always change it later.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <Form {...form}>
          <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
            <div className="space-y-8 px-6">
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center text-center">
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="imageUrl"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormControl>
                        <FileUpload
                          endpoint="serverImage"
                          value={field.value}
                          onChange={field.onChange}
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
              </div>
              <FormField
                name="name"
                control={form.control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel className="text-xs font-bold uppercase text-zinc-50 dark:text-secondary/70">
                      Server name
                    </FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        disabled={isLoading}
                        className="border-0 bg-zinc-300/50 text-black focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-offset-0"
                        placeholder="Enter server name"
                        {...field}
                      ></Input>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>
            <DialogFooter className="bg-gray-100 px-6 py-4">
              <Button variant="primary" disabled={isLoading} className="w-full">
                Create
              </Button>
            </DialogFooter>
          </form>
        </Form>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

The component utilizes useEffect to avoid server-side rendering, but I'm still encountering hydration errors upon rendering. The component is structured within a Dialog from a UI library, and it's used as part of a modal system within the application.

In the layout.tsx file, the ModalProvider component is used to conditionally render the CreateServerModal component:

```js
"use client";

import { CreateServerModal } from "@/components/modals/create-server-modal";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const ModalProvider = () => {
  const [isMounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!isMounted) return null;

  return (
    <>
      <CreateServerModal />
    </>
  );
};
```

Despite the site rendering successfully, the console displays hydration errors, as shown in the screenshots below:
[image: Site rendered but still throwing error]
[image: First error]

[image: second error]

[image: third error]

I've verified that Next.js is up to date. Can anyone help identify what might be causing these hydration errors and suggest a solution?